# Join tables, select all but rename few SQL BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to join two tables which have 4 identical column names (ID, FieldID, FieldCropYear, UpdateUTC). I want to join those two tables on FieldID.

I used this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `xxx.yyy.111` AS ACT
    INNER JOIN `xxx.yyy.222` AS BOUND
    ON BOUND.FieldID = ACT.FieldID
    AND BOUND.FieldCropYear = ACT.FieldCropYear
```

After running it, i get the following error: `Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): ID, FieldID, FieldCropYear, UpdateUTC`

Is it possible to select * but rename those 4 columns in one dataframe? What is the most efficient way to deal with it? 
Is it possible something like:

```
    SELECT * 
EXCEPT(ID, FieldID, UpdateUTC, FieldCropYear), 
                     ID as ID_b,
                     FieldID as FieldID_b,
                     UpdateUTC as UpdateUTC_b,
                     FieldCropYear as FieldCropYear_b
FROM `xxx.yyy.222` AS BOUND
    INNER JOIN `xxx.yyy.111` AS ACT
    ON BOUND.FieldID_b = ACT.FieldID
    AND BOUND.FieldCropYear_b = ACT.FieldCropYear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `using()` instead of `on`- but there you have to use all the fields:

```sql
 SELECT * FROM `xxx.yyy.111` AS ACT
    INNER JOIN `xxx.yyy.222` AS BOUND
    USING(ID, FieldID, FieldCropYear,UpdateUTC)
```

If that doesn't make sense because some of the fields are actually different, then rename some of the fields in a subquery:

```sql
 SELECT * FROM `xxx.yyy.111` AS ACT
    INNER JOIN 
     (select * EXCEPT(ID, UpdateUTC), ID AS actID, UpdateUTC as actUpdateUTC FROM `xxx.yyy.222`) AS BOUND
    USING(FieldID, FieldCropYear)
```

Didn't test the code but I hope the approaches are clear

Comment: I tried second suggestion. It works perfectly and that's exactly what i need! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

BigQuery does *exactly* what you want using [`replace`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_replace):

```
SELECT bound.*,
       act.* REPLACE (id as id_act,
                      filedid as fieldid_act,
                      UpdateUTC as UpdateUTC_act,
                      FieldCropYear as FieldCropYear_act
                     )
FROM `xxx.yyy.222` BOUND JOIN
     `xxx.yyy.111` AS ACT
     ON BOUND.FieldID_b = ACT.FieldID AND
        BOUND.FieldCropYear_b = ACT.FieldCropYear;
```

Note:  When I want to select columns from tables that have overlapping names, I often select them as records:

```
SELECT BOUND, ACT
FROM . . .
```

I'm not sure if this works for your purposes, though.